# My iOS project can't run in visionOS simulator with Xcode 15.2 in Apple silicon MacBook

Tags: ios, visionos, visionos-simulator

When run for visionOS (Design for iPad) simulator, it always fails with the  message:

> iKM's architectures (Intel 64-bit) include none that Apple Vision Pro can execute (arm64)

And in my project I exclude arm64 architecture for iOS simulator SDK (because some CocoaPods lib can't compile for arm64 with simulator before).

But it seems when compile for visionOS simulator with Design for iPad, it uses only arm64 architecture **(which seems not necessarily in the early version of Xcode, and in the early version of Xcode my iOS project can run well in visionOS simulator, maybe it's because the the visionos simulator can run in non-m1 MacBook for the early beta version)**

**I think the core problem behind is: the project exclude arm64 will work well for iOS simulator in Apple Silicon, but can't work for visionOS simulator in Apple Silicon** . Is there any way to make vision os simulator works as the iOS simulator